# dropdown menu disappears after a second without any selection in asp

Tags: asp.net, drop-down-menu

i am working on an asp.net project with SQL Server. I have used many dropdowns on various points. all was working fine yesterday. but today when i started my project with no changes, dropdowns are not working properly. when i click, list shows up for a second and then disappear. what could be the problem? Sorry, code is too large to upload.

Comment: Upload a representative sample of your code.

Comment: wherever i used autopostback=true, it is creating problem. but if i remove it how can i launch selectedIndexChanged event?

Comment: Again, we need to see some code that is representative of what you're doing in order to know how to help you.